# Swap resource-files in .NET exe?

Tags: .net, resources, reflector

.NET Reflector can dissassemble .NET-files beautifully but I found no way to swap resource-files (pictures) from within an assembly.

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options availabe to edit "WIN32" resources (like StringTables, VersionInfo, Icons, Dialog Templates, etc.)

- Visual Studio itself (just open the binary)
- [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)
- [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/)

Note however, that those are not capable of editing .NET resources (created from a .RESX file).

Comment: I have a feeling you may be able to use Reflexil for .NET resources: not 100% certain of that though.